# How to remove line below figure

Tags: floats, captions

I insere a figure on my document and then a line below appears, how can I remove that?

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{PAW transformation for the radial part of the hydrogen wave function \cite{balluff2017ab}}
\label{fig:PAW_transformation}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PAW_transformation}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not believe that the information that you provide is enough for people to help you. From your code I do not see any indication why there should be a line unless the line is part of the picture. Maybe it's a problem with your PDF viewer, maybe try a different viewer.

Comment: Thank you @Dr.ManuelKuehner, I will do that.